# How to create an index on two fields within MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a MYSQL query that's under performing. I need to create an index on two fields within my query: `cancel` and `complete`.
What is the best way to perform this?

`SELECT* FROM table WHERE cancel != 'CANCEL' AND complete IN ('COMPLETE','TAKEN_BACK')`

Answer (score 1):

To create a multi-column index, but the column names in parentheses.

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD INDEX (cancel, complete);
```

This is equivalent to

```
CREATE INDEX table_cancel_complete_ix
ON table (cancel, complete);
```

`CREATE INDEX` requires you to give a name to the index, it's optional with `ALTER TABLE` (it will be assigned a default name).

Comment: how would I apply that to the above select?

Comment: It's done automatically. If an index exists, MySQL will use it if it can.

Comment: Or rather, what if I wanted to index cancel first and then complete?

Comment: That's the order of the index I defined. You can reverse them if you want.

Comment: An index will be used if you just look up a prefix of it, so the above index will be used if you just specify `cancel` in the query, but not if you just look for `complete`.

Comment: So, in order for me to create an index on cancel and complete (in that order), I'd need to do this: SELECT * FROM table and then  ALTER TABLE table
ADD INDEX (cancel, complete);

Comment: It's not part of the query, this is a permanent change you make to the database.

Comment: You do it BEFORE the query, so that the query is able to use the index.

Comment: Hey sorry, I think I miss represented my question, I meant creating an index, eg. CREATE INDEX ON [table]([column name],[column name]);

Comment: `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX` are equivalent.

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql is a good tutorial on creating indexes

Answer (score 0):

To add an index over more than one column (aka [multi-column index](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-composite-index/) or composite index), use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD INDEX (cancel, complete);
```

However, you might want to make sure this is the reason for your statement to be underperforming. Take a look into [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to dig deeper into this.